# If $\int \phi f d\lambda =\int \phi g d\lambda $ then $f=g$ a.e.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

If $\int \phi f d\lambda =\int \phi g d\lambda $ then $f=g$ a.e. for every $\phi \in C_0(G)$. Note: $f,g \in L^1(G)$ .

I know that if  $\int \phi (f-g) =0$ then $\phi (f-g)=0$. Since $\phi$ isn't zero then $f-g=0$.

Do you think my proof is true? Please help me.

$C_0(G)$ is the set of continuous functions that tend to zero at infinity.

Comment: Are you talking about definite or indefinite integrals?

Comment: @user88595 He means integrate over $G$, which is some abstract measure space with some kind of topology.

Comment: $\int \phi(f-g) = 0$ does NOT necessarily imply $\phi(f-g) = 0$.  Your proof is not correct.

Comment: "I know that ∫ϕ(f−g)=0 then ϕ(f−g)=0" Sorry?

Comment: @Did how does the OP define $C_0(G)$ without topology?

Comment: sorry .I dont know

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Indeed. Silly me.

Comment: how i can prove this?

Comment: @saeed You can use $\int \phi(f-g) = 0$ for all $\phi$ to imply $\int_A (f-g) = 0$ for all measurable $A$.  If $G$ is something like the real line, then you show that $I_A$ can be approximated by a suitable $\phi$.

Comment: If $G$ is not specified, you need to state the hypotheses that $G$ satisfies.  For example, I think you need the measure to be defined on the Baire measurable sets, not the Borel sets.  This is a technical issue, and I hope you have enough hypotheses on $G$ so you don't need to mess with this.

Comment: The way I said the comment before the previous is not the unique way to do it, but something along those lines is what you need.

Comment: Your quantification looks weird.  I assume you mean "If $\int\ldots=\int\ldots$ for every $\phi\in C_0(G)$ then $f=g$ a.e."

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes.it means

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$
\int\varphi(f-g)=0, \quad \text{for all}\,\,\, \varphi\in C_0(G).
$$
But every integrable function can be approximated, in the $L^2$-norm, by functions $C_0(G)$. In particular, there exist a sequence $\{\varphi_n\}\subset C_0(G)$, such that $\|f-g-\varphi_n\|_{L^2(G)}\to 0$. Then 
\begin{align}
\int(f-g)^2 &=\int (f-g)\varphi_n+\int (f-g)(f-g-\varphi_n)=\int (f-g)(f-g-\varphi_n) \\
&\le \|f-g\| \|f-g-\varphi_n\|\to 0.
\end{align}
Thus $\int (f-g)^2=0$, which implies that $f(x)-g(x)=0$, a.e.

Comment: This requires $f-g$ to be $L^2$.

Comment: By the way, what is $G$? - It $C_0(G)$ the set of continuous functions with compact support?